# Adding attachments in couchdb using an update function

Tags: couchdb, attachment

How do I add attachments to couchdb using an update function? In my couchapp I would like all interactions with the database to go through show, list and update functions for better security.

I think I can delete attachments with an update function (although I don't think I should really update the _attachments field directly). I am using:

```
function(doc, req){
    if (doc) {
        delete doc._attachments[req.form.filename];
        return [doc, JSON.stringify(doc)];
    }
    else {
        return [null, "Document does not exist."];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new attachments in update function with easy - just [inline](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/common.html#creating-multiple-attachments) them into doc body:

```js
function(doc, req){
    if (doc) {
        // attachment delete
        delete doc._attachments[req.form.filename];
        // add another one
        doc._attachments.hello = {
            "content_type": "text/plain", // required
            "data": "d29ybGQ=" //world
        }
        return [doc, JSON.stringify(doc)];
    }
    else {
        return [null, "Document does not exist."];
    }
}
```